# How to recover a message mistakenly identified as spam by Inbox?

Tags: spam-prevention, inbox-by-gmail

I found a non-spam message that was automatically placed in spam folder (a false positive). In the Gmail interface, I would click "Not spam" to remove the message from spam folder. But I could not find any such action in the Inbox interface.

How can I tell Inbox that this message (a) was not spam, and (b) should not be deleted in 30 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Remove from Spam

1. Open the email you found in Spam.
2. Select Pin [image].

Your message will move back to your inbox. You can quickly find it again by clicking the switch at the top of the inbox [image].

[Source](https://support.google.com/inbox/answer/6070440?hl=en).